# angular datepicker why calendar box is closed after click away

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

This is the link of the the example I am talking about.

Go to the link
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
then check the datepicker example in plunker.

If we look in the code, I don't see any magic code there to do the closing part.

All I see is

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
   $scope.status.opened = true;
};
```

which only opens the calendar.

My questions is how does it close on a click event that is outside of the calendar. This is a pretty good feature that I want to have on my other directives too.
---------------------Temp Solution----------------
Since no1 have provided an answer yet. For any1 who wants to know how to do this. I have a temp solution for you guys. 
1. Add ng-click on the outter most tag.
2. Add ng-mouseleave and ng-mouseenter event on your custom tag.
Here is the flow:
When user mouse out/in of your custom tag. You set a flag to true/false.
Then when user clicks, close the div when mouse is outside the custom tag (You will use the flag to check ).

Comment: Can you please tell me what actually do you want to ask. ui.bootstrap.datepicker is actually a module and it has codes written behind it. To use it we inject it as dependency, and it has been made such that whenever you click outside the opened view it closes.

Comment: But I don't understand what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the feature which whenever you click outside the opened view it closes. I want to know how this works. If I was doing this feature, this would have a hover out/in event listener and click listener. The click listener will close the calender when the hoverOut flag is true.

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself.
It is because of the following code.

```
var documentClickBind = function(event) {
    if (scope.isOpen && event.target !== element[0]) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.isOpen = false;
      });
    }
  };
```